# What to show in the landing page of UPI transfers?

Tags: workflow, usability-engineering

In the banking sector, we are implementing the UPI Transfers (pertinent to Indian and Indian banks). Is it good to give home screen showing all menu options to the customers before they create Virtual Payment Address (VPA).
to explore all the features?

or

ask them to first register VPA and then allow them to explore.

What would be your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as best practices for UX go, **always give the user all the information** before asking them to provide any sort of details.

Obviously, this rule may vary slightly depending upon the use case but generally you want the user to be aware of things like:

- Is their data private?
- Is their data protected? If yes, how?
- Why are they being asked for this information?
- What are the alternatives (if any) / What if they don't?

This builds user's trust and also helps them choose, not to mention the numerous legal reasons.

*PS: I haven't used the UPI method personally so if there's any specific thing that I need to know about it then kindly add it to the question of mention it in the comments*